# Output src of track kind div

Tags: php, regex, extract, file-get-contents, webvtt

How can I output the SRC of the following div using php file_get_content from a given website?

```
<div class="videocontainer">
<input type="file" id="srtSelector"/>
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" id="olvideo">
<track kind="captions" src="https://rolled.oped.info/sub/jAghd9t8AB4/HfQZ32SovcY.vtt"/>
</video>
</div>
```

I'm interested in displaying the https://rolled.oped.info/sub/jAghd9t8AB4/HfQZ32SovcY.vtt part.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The HTML around `kind="captions src="https:` is also broken and not entirely sure if/how it works.

Comment: @NigelRen fixed the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to try and use DOM rather than using regex's etc.  DOMDocument is not always simple to use, but for your problem it may do the job...

```
$html = <<< HTML
<div class="videocontainer">
<input type="file" id="srtSelector"/>
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" id="olvideo">
<track kind="captions" src="https://rolled.oped.info/sub/jAghd9t8AB4/HfQZ32SovcY.vtt"/>
</video>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$tracks = $dom->getElementsByTagName("track");

foreach ( $tracks as $track )   {
    echo (string)$track->getAttribute("src").PHP_EOL;
}
```

The code should be easy enough to follow.

The biggest problem you can face is that if the HTML has errors (like the original one in the question) then this sometimes can make it difficult to  load.

Comment: Thanks, but when I'm using `var_dump($tracks);` on your code, I'm getting `object(DOMNodeList)#2 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }` otherwise, the page is blank with no errors into the console.

Comment: Does the example code work?  If so, then it is most likely the page your trying to access.  If you fixed the problem with the HTML manually (from the comment on the question) then the original HTML is probably still broken.  If you let me know the URL your using I may be able to try it.

Comment: This is the source code of the website: https://pastebin.com/raw/HzccWpEw

Comment: I've copied the linked source to a HTML file and loaded it and get the output I was expecting (https://thumb.oloadcdn.net/subtitle/jAghd9t8AB4/HfQZ32SovcY.vtt).

Comment: (to load from a file change load line to `$dom->loadHTMLFile("sourcefile.html");`)

Comment: My current code looks like this and it doesn't work: https://pastebin.com/raw/xYHYxGXf =/

Comment: One thing to do is to have a look at the HTML coming back from the page.  Probably because I'm not a user it gives me a page which looks as though it's asking me to login.  It also has some text which says 'We can't find the file you are looking for. It maybe got deleted by the owner or was removed due a copyright violation.'

Comment: I don't see any reason to transtype an attribute value that is always a string with `(string)`. If you want to be sure the src attribute exist, use `if ( $track->hasAttribute('src') ) ...`